# Replace string outside "" only in Sublime using regular expression

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a long list (about 100k lines) of strings in my file like this:

```
job_title <- map["job_title"]
....
```

I want to do some replacement to make it like this:

```
jobTitle <- map["job_title"]
```

so I just replace `_t` to `T`, but I want the left side only.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: I dont know what to try =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace `_t` with `T`, you will replace all occurrences of `_t` with `T` regardless of the context.

What you may try is to match all `"..."` substrings and skip them, and then match any letter after `_` and convert it to uppercase. How you match `"..."` substrings depends on whether escaped entities may appear in your text or not.

If there can be no escaped quotes,

**Search**: `"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(?!)|_([A-Za-z])`
**Replace**: `\u$1`

If there can be escaped quotes:

**Search**: `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(?!)|_([A-Za-z])`
**Replace**: `\u$1`

[image]

**Details**:

- `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(?!)` - a `"..."` substring (it matches `"`, then any 0+ chars other than `"` and `\` and then 0+ sequences of any escaped char (`\\.`) followed with any 0+ chars other than `"` and `\`, and then `"`) that is matched and then omitted from the match, and the next match is searched for after the end of the current match (due to `(*SKIP)(?!)`)
- `|` - or
- `_` - a `_` char
- `([A-Za-z])` - Capturing group 1: any ASCII letter

The `\u` operator in the replacement makes the first char after it uppercase. `$1` stands for the letter captured with `([a-zA-Z])`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for regex in your case (press Ctr+H and replace all)

Replace

```
job_title <
```

with:

```
jobTitle <
```

Comment: i think u ddnt get what I mean. if u use, it will replace both strings.

Answer (score 0):

With the following regex you match just the first _t

```
(?<=^job)_(\w)
```

so you could replace that with T.

See https://regex101.com/r/VcpAzt/1